# Setting up VPN on Ubuntu VPS @ linode

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, vps, openvpn, linode

I'm really struggling with this because I'm not a network admin, only a mortal programmer.

Linode gives you an external and internal IP for use with other nodes on the linode network. In my case I've configured my external interface like this:

```
# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Configuration for eth0 and aliases

# This line ensures that the interface will be brought up during boot.
auto eth0 eth0:0 eth0:1

# eth0 - This is the main IP address that will be used for most outbound connec$
# The address, netmask and gateway are all necessary.
iface eth0 inet static
 address 97.107.XXX.XX
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 97.107.XXX.1


# eth0:1 - Private IPs have no gateway (they are not publicly routable) so all $
# specify is the address and netmask.
iface eth0:1 inet static
 address 192.168.140.135
 netmask 255.255.128.0
```

What's missing here before eth0:1 is the interface eth0:0 which I want to use for my VPN. Do I have to do this? Well I added this to my interfaces file between eth0 and eth0:1

```
iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 10.10.10.1
 netmask 255.0.0.0
```

So I've started installing openvpn and generated the keys. This worked, as far as I can judge. I'm having problems with the openvpn server configuration. I want to be able to access my VPS' files from home or on the go, and maybe access the internet through it (maybe at a later stage, I don't know, I'm mainly interested in having access to my VPS and its files)

Among others, I have the following in my **server.conf**

```
dev tap1
server-bridge 10.10.10.1 255.0.0.0 10.10.10.50 10.10.10.100
```

Is this correct? Or do I have to use something else there.

I added some iptables mumbo jumbo for the bridges.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tap0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

It says tap0 here even tho everywhere else it's tap1. I'm getting these numbers from a guide (http://www.linode.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN). I don't know whether this is correct.

I then created a **bridge-start** script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #################################
 # Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
 # Requires: bridge-utils
 #################################
 # Define Bridge Interface
 br="br0"
 # Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
 # for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
 tap="tap1"
 # Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
 # with TAP interface(s) above.
 eth="eth0:0"
 eth_ip="10.10.10.1"
 eth_netmask="255.0.0.0"
 eth_broadcast="10.10.10.255"
 for t in $tap; do
   openvpn --mktun --dev $t
 done
```

Again, I have no idea what I'm actually doing here... Since I decided to use 10.10.10.1 I guess the default netmask would be 255.0.0.0. I've also added a similar **bridge-stop** script. Anyways if I want to start my **bridge-start** script I'm getting:

```
kitsune@makemake:/etc/openvpn/# /etc/openvpn/bridge-start
Thu Jun 25 21:08:36 2009 TUN/TAP device tap1 opened
Thu Jun 25 21:08:36 2009 Persist state set to: ON
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address
```

When I then try to start the openvpn it **fails.**

Can anybody make sense of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That wiki article is complete and utter balls.  Don't use OpenVPN bridging unless you really, *really* know why you want to use it.  It makes everything about 100 times harder.  I'd start with the official [OpenVPN HOWTO](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) and go from there.

Comment: Seconded times a billion!  That article should die in a fire. Imma tell phil to write one to replace it.